# Cryptic Family Reunion: Everyone knows it's Windy

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues

The answer to this puzzle is a list of ten thematically related words or proper names or phrases. Each of these is clued cryptically, and the theme is to be determined. Since the definition part of a cryptic clue would give away the theme, these cryptic clues use a family member (e.g., mom, sister) to stand in for the definition part of the clue. So for example, if the theme of the puzzle were chemical elements, "Sister picking at nit" would clue "tin". Clues are sorted with answers in alphabetical order, and lengths of each answer are given with the clues. I hope you enjoy!

1. Brother is salty: water giant mangled a piercer (10)
2. Daughter is force in Olympic sport, placing third in curling (6)
3. Pa taking in woman at last, firstly conditionally emancipating son (7)
4. Sister care-free after cut-down (7)
5. Approach store with Mom (4)
6. "Oklahoman banking the domain of Switzerland", insinuates Grandpa (8)
7. Nephew floats where waters come together (5)
8. Pa taking in woman at last, firstly conditionally emancipating son (4)
9. Uncle to dispose hoof, chine, head after decapitating climbing goat (5)
10. Wife to steer left or right? Left (4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are

> types of sailboats (as clued by the title - sailboats need wind)

Clues:

Brother is salty: water giant mangled a piercer (10)

> BRI(GANTI)*NE (thanks @jafe)

Daughter is force in Olympic sport, placing third in curling (6)

> LUG(G)E + R

Pa taking in woman at last, firstly conditionally emancipating son (7)

> P(IN + _N)A + C_ E_

Sister care-free after cut-down (7)

> LOP< + CARE* for POLACRE (thanks @jafe)

Approach store with Mom (4)

> apPROAch (Thanks @El-Guest)

"Oklahoman banking the domain of Switzerland", insinuates Grandpa (8)

> S(CH)OONER

Nephew floats where waters come together (5)

> SLOOP as in POOLS< (thanks jafe)

Pa taking in woman at last, firstly conditionally emancipating son (4)

> SNO*+W (thanks jafe)

Uncle to dispose hoof, chine, head after decapitating climbing goat (5)

> headless IBEX< + _E + C_ = XEBEC

Wife to steer left or right? Left (4)

> YAW+L

Note: Should I community wiki this answer because I didn't do most of the work?

Comment: Second last one is rot13(LNPUG).

Comment: First one's rot13(OEV(TNAGV*)AR).

Comment: @El-Guest: I had guessed that based on the enumeration but couldn't figure out the wordplay

Comment: @jafe: thanks! though what does rot13(n cvrepre) have to do with it?

Comment: For #1 — probably means rot13(cvrepvat) one word with the other.

Comment: Interesting, makes sense

Comment: You had an edit for a four letter word for “Pa taking in woman...” that you deleted. I think you’ll find that word directly in the “Approach store with Mom” clue...

Comment: Ohhh I see now.

Comment: The Pa one I think is rot13(F_ + P_ + _BJ), but if it is then the nephew one is going to be hard to find....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109106/discussion-between-forgotten-user-and-el-guest).

Comment: As of 1637 UTC, all are correct except #9.

Comment: @Forgotten_User — you might as well take the credit haha

Comment: That's it! Except there is a type in the wordplay for 3...too many of one letter.